# DELETE FROM is not working (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-delete

What my code makes is, if the state of a project is finalised, deletes the project from a table and inserts it to another table by picking up the reference. The thing is that it inserts the register to the other table but it does not delete the register from the previous table. **Maybe here is the problem, the reference is like this: ST9999_15 or ST8888_15. Maybe the underscore is the problem**.

```
if ($state="Finalised") {
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `proyectos_en_curso` WHERE `referencia`='$reference'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $name=$row['name'];
    $ling_comb=$row['combinacion_linguistica'];
    $date=$row['fecha_entrega_cliente'];
    mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `proyectos_en_curso` WHERE `referencia`='ST9999_15'");
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `proyectos_entregados` 
    (`name`, `referencia`, `combinacion_linguistica`, `fecha_entrega_cliente`) 
    VALUES ('$name', '$reference', 
    '$ling_comb', '$date')");
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It is not clear enough

Comment: check using echo "DELETE FROM `proyectos_en_curso` WHERE `referencia`='ST9999_15'"; what o/p come for this code.

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: try this once:
`$sql = "DELETE FROM  WHERE proyectos_en_curso WHERE referencia='ST9999_15'";
$con->exec($sql);`

Comment: and also provide more information about your table, schema. Can you manually operate the same on that or not'

Comment: @KarthikKeyan it displays literally the code: DELETE FROM proyectos_en_curso WHERE referencia='ST9999_15'

Comment: I think the query is correct, pls check the table name and field name 
i am not sure, try referencia=ST9999_15 remove the single cots and check it

Comment: First Check select query working fine ?

Comment: Is the call to `mysqli_query` returning false?  Try `if (!mysqli_query("DELETE...")) {echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error; die();}` to see if there's an error being returned.

Comment: @KarthikKeyan table and field names are correct. referencia=ST9999_15 without the cots does not work and select query is working fine.

Comment: @daiscog no errors being returned

Comment: i think do u assign any child table for this 'proyectos_en_curso' table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked! It was a stupid connecting error. I was entering the db through the query "mysqli_connect("SERVER","USER","PASS","DB")" and as USER, I put the secondary user with hardly no privileges so I changed the user to one with deleting privileges and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `proyectos_en_curso` WHERE `referencia`='ST9999_15';
```

Check this code in your mysql database. It shows what is the error and you can easily clear it.

Comment: It works when I do the consult directly from phpmyadmin; it deletes the row.

Comment: mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `proyectos_en_curso` WHERE `referencia`='ST9999_15'") or Die ("error in querr");    Fine then try this in code. It shows what is error.

Comment: It shows "error in querr" so the query is not correctly stated?

Comment: Yes check the query, you may misplaced the word or something int the query, check clearly